# Merge with same target and source table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table where I want to check if record exists leave it alone, if not insert new row and update previous row. I am wondering if I can use merge here like below ?

```
  CREATE TABLE a
  (keycol INT PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 INT NOT NULL,
  col2 INT NOT NULL,
  col3 INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,0,0,0),(2,0,0,0);

MERGE INTO a
USING select 1 from a where col1 = 3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
col2 = 2,
col2 = 2,
col3 = 2
where col1 = 3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
INSERT (keycol, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (4, 0, 0, 0)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Should that first condition be `WHEN MATCHED` - when `NOT MATCHED` you won't have a row to update and will need to insert

Comment: please read question when nothing matches I want to insert and update

Comment: I did read it, and your proposed solution is nonsense.  When there is not a match, you want to update **what**?  There is no row to update.  You want to update every other row in the table?

Comment: What is the "previous row"? Where does table alias `b` come from? you do not have a `on` condition, what do you want to use to match rows between source and target?

Comment: I updated Queries, does that make sense now?

Comment: @user570715 - nope.  why do you want to insert a row then update it?  Why not just insert the right values the first time?

Answer (score 4):

```
MERGE INTO a
   USING (
          VALUES (3,3,2,2),
                 (4,0,0,0)
         ) AS source (keycol, col1, col2, col3)
   ON a.keycol = source.keycol
      AND a.col1 = source.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET col2 = source.col2,
          col3 = source.col3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
   INSERT (keycol, col1, col2, col3)
      VALUES (keycol, col1, col2, col3);
```

Comment: That's IMHO the correct answer - at least it works for me for exact this question :)